# My list doesn't clear itself when being called recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I am fresh in learning Python and wanted to try something after watching a video on YouTube by Veritasium titled ["The Simplest Math Problem No One Can Solve"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=094y1Z2wpJg)

essentially:
If x is even, divide x by 2
If x is odd, times 3 then plus 1
keep repeating until x = 1

So I wrote this piece of code to get the list of results for a range of numbers

```
val = int(input("Enter a Number"))

def threexplus1(x, count = 1, mylist=[]):
    if x == 1: 
        mylist.append(x)
        return count, mylist
    elif x%2==0:
        mylist.append(x)
        return threexplus1(int(x/2), count+1)
    else:
        mylist.append(x)
        return threexplus1(int(x*3+1), count+1)

for x in range (1,val+1):
    print (x)
    print (threexplus1(x))
```

input

```
4
```

The output I want is not the output I hope for

The current Output:

```
Enter a Number  4
1
(1, [1])
2
(2, [1, 2, 1])
3
(8, [1, 2, 1, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1])
4
(3, [1, 2, 1, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1])
```

The output I wanted:

```
Enter a Number  4
1
(1, [1])
2
(2, [2, 1])
3
(8, [3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1])
4
(3, [4, 2, 1])
```

I am wondering why mylist doesn't refresh/clear itself when it is called recursively?

Comment: I think the list is defined only once during compilation of the code

Comment: Remove the default value for `mylist` and pass it explicitly in each recursive call.